# Flutter: Consumer triggered when soft keyboard is closed

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a prefix icon in **TextField**. After tapping it , I get a string from service and by provider and Consumer I attached this string into TextField controller.

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (context) => provider,
  child: Consumer<FacilitiesProvider>(
    builder: (context, value, child) {
      if (value.dateString != null &&
          value.dateString.isNotEmpty) {
        _controller.text = value.dateString;
      }
      return TextField(
        controller: _controller,
```

Everything is ok .The problem is here.

When user tapped on TextField, soft keyboard is opened and when user deleted string and close the soft keyboard, Consumer is triggered and again `value.dateString` set in **_controller** and again string is shown!!!

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your Widget tree is rebuilt when the keyboard shows/hides, causing your build method to be called again. The best solution is to handle the value assignment elsewhere, but if you are not concerned with the keyboard hiding part of the screen, you can set `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` in your `Scaffold` to `false`. If this does cover anything up, you can wrap the `body` in a `SingleChildScrollView`.